# how to deal with bit fields in Julia when writing a wrapper of C

Tags: julia

```
typedef struct {
uint32_t is_bin:1, is_write:1, is_be:1, is_cram:1, dummy:28;
int64_t lineno;
kstring_t line;
char *fn, *fn_aux;
union {
    BGZF *bgzf;
    struct cram_fd *cram;
struct hFILE *hfile;
    void *voidp;
} fp;
htsFormat format;
} htsFile;
```

how to deal with the bit fields part of `htsFile` in Julia? 
If I am not care about the specific value `uint32_t is_bin:1, is_write:1, is_be:1, is_cram:1, dummy:28;`, can I just use a Cuint variable to repalce it in julia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I just use a Cuint variable to replace it in julia?

Yes, the alignment will be the same. If you do need the values, you can use bitmasks to select the required bit(s).

As a side note, the [StrPack](https://github.com/pao/StrPack.jl) package may be of interest for dealing with complicated struct [de]serialization (although I don't think it has built-in bitfield support).

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the individual bits using julia'a bitwise manipulation functions (`&`, `>>`, etc.) You could define convenience functions like `is_bin(x) = (x & 0x01) > 0`.